# How to fix image quality on PHP (GD)?

Tags: php, gd

I have been trying to solve the border-image problem for many days, but I still can't come to a decision.. I really need your help!

I have code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/matrix/images/1/1f/Monica_Bellucci_Dolce_and_Gabbana.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130227074822');
$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);

$border = imagecreatefrompng('http://meson.ad-l.ink/8mRbHMnS9/thumb.png');
$borderW = imagesx($border);
$borderH = imagesy($border);

$borderSize = 70;


// New image width and height

$isHorizontalAlign = true;

$coProp = $w / $h;

if ($coProp > 1)
    $isHorizontalAlign = false;

if ($isHorizontalAlign) {
    $newWidth = $w - $borderSize * 2;
    $newHeight = $newWidth * ($h / $w);
} else {
    $newHeight = $h - $borderSize * 2;
    $newWidth = $newHeight * ($w / $h);
}


// Transparent border

$indent = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

//imagesavealpha($indent, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($indent, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($indent, 0, 0, $color);


$paddingLeft = ($w - $newWidth) / 2;
$paddingTop = ($h - $newHeight) / 2;

imagecopyresampled($indent, $image, $paddingLeft, $paddingTop, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $w, $h);


// New border width

$x1 = $newWidth;
$x2 = $borderSize;
$x3 = (int)($x1 / $x2);

if ($x3 == $x1 / $x2)
    $bw = $borderSize;
else {
    $x4 = $x1 - $x3 * $x2;
    $x5 = $x4 / $x3;
    $x2 = $x2 + $x5;

    $bw = $x2;
}


// New border height

$y1 = $newHeight;
$y2 = $borderSize;
$y3 = (int)($y1 / $y2);

if ($y3 == $y1 / $y2)
    $bh = $borderSize;
else {
    $y4 = $y1 - $y3 * $y2;
    $y5 = $y4 / $y3;
    $y2 = $y2 + $y5;

    $bh = $y2;
}


// Horizontal

$percent1 = $bw / $borderSize;

$borderNewWidth1 = (int)$borderW * $percent1;
$borderNewHeight1 = (int)$borderH * $percent1;

$thumb1 = imagecreatetruecolor($borderNewWidth1, $borderNewHeight1);
imagesavealpha($thumb1, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb1, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($thumb1, 0, 0, $color);
imagecopyresized($thumb1, $border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $borderNewWidth1, $borderNewHeight1, $borderW, $borderH);


// Vertical

$percent2 = $bh / $borderSize;

$borderNewWidth2 = (int)$borderW * $percent2;
$borderNewHeight2 = (int)$borderH * $percent2;

$thumb2 = imagecreatetruecolor($borderNewWidth2, $borderNewHeight2);
imagesavealpha($thumb2, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($thumb2, 0, 0, $color);
imagecopyresized($thumb2, $border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $borderNewWidth2, $borderNewHeight2, $borderW, $borderH);


// Angles

$borderNewWidth3 = (int)$borderW * $percent1;
$borderNewHeight3 = (int)$borderH * $percent2;

$thumb3 = imagecreatetruecolor($borderNewWidth3, $borderNewHeight3);
imagesavealpha($thumb3, true);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb3, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($thumb3, 0, 0, $color);
imagecopyresized($thumb3, $border, 0, 0, 0, 0, $borderNewWidth3, $borderNewHeight3, $borderW, $borderH);


// Horizontal border

$horizontalX = ($w - $newWidth) / 2;
$horizontalY = (($h - $newHeight) / 2 - $bw) + 1;
$horizontalY2 = $h - ($h - $newHeight) / 2;

for ($i = 0; $i < round($newWidth / $bw); $i++) {
    // Top
    imagecopy($indent, $thumb1, $horizontalX + ($i * $bw), $horizontalY, $borderSize * $percent1, 0, $bw + 1, $bw);

    // Bottom
    imagecopy($indent, $thumb1, $horizontalX + ($i * $bw), $horizontalY2, $borderSize * $percent1, $borderSize * 2 * $percent1, $bw + 1, $bw - 1);
}


// Vertical border

$verticalY = ($h - $newHeight) / 2;
$verticalX = (($w - $newWidth) / 2 - $bh) + 1;
$verticalX2 = $w - ($w - $newWidth) / 2;

for ($i = 0; $i < round($newHeight / $bh); $i++) {
    // Left
    imagecopy($indent, $thumb2, $verticalX, $verticalY + ($i * $bh), 0, $borderSize * $percent2, $bh, $bh + 1);

    // Right
    imagecopy($indent, $thumb2, $verticalX2, $verticalY + ($i * $bh), ($borderSize * $percent2) * 2, $borderSize * $percent2, $bh, $bh + 1);
}


// Left top border
imagecopy($indent, $thumb3, (($w - $newWidth) / 2 - $bw) + 1, (($h - $newHeight) / 2 - $bh) + 1, 0, 0, $bw, $bh);

// Left bottom border
imagecopy($indent, $thumb3, (($w - $newWidth) / 2 - $bw) + 1, $h - ($h - $newHeight) / 2, 0, ($borderSize * 2) * $percent2, $bw, $bh);

// Right top border
imagecopy($indent, $thumb3, $w - ($w - $newWidth) / 2, (($h - $newHeight) / 2 - $bh) + 1, ($borderSize * 2) * $percent1, 0, $bw, $bh);

// Right bottom border
imagecopy($indent, $thumb3, $w - ($w - $newWidth) / 2, $h - ($h - $newHeight) / 2, ($borderSize * 2) * $percent1, ($borderSize * 2) * $percent2, $bw, $bh);

// Save result to base64

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($indent);
```

(by default I have a transparent background, but for an example I removed it)

When image sizes are large - everything works perfectly:
https://i.gyazo.com/028f5834efe968a7295194600fac684b.png

But when I add a small image, it's quality is significantly reduced. Look at this:
[image]

I do not know how to fix this..

P.S.: I'm trying to do frame for my photo using similar border-image: http://polariton.ad-l.ink/8mRbHMnS9/thumb.png
The calculations that I did cost a lot of effort, but the result I could not achieve..

Thank you for attention!
I hope to solve the problem.

Comment: You may have a better time splitting this into 2 questions one regarding the quality which is a programming issue, the other regarding the issue with repeating at the bottom may be better suited to the math forum..

Comment: Small errors fixed. I just change this (int) ($newWidth / $bw) on round and also in the second for.

Comment: The quality of your border issue is because the angle is falling between pixels. As you don't seem to have any anti aliasing going on it seems to be picking the nearest whole pixel.

Comment: Ints being whole numbers makes sense for the quality issue.

Comment: The math side of things I think you need to work out how many zig-zags would fit within the height, as the image is size is variable you need to work out how many whole zig zags will fit and then increase the canvas size to accompany the Ceil() of that number.

Comment: Don't ceil, floor and round. GD make it. But for quality, you should use imagemagic. It fastly and can be choose filters/compisiting quality (smooth algo, zoom, compression, etc).